No viable conversion from 'unique_ptr<Derived>' to 'unique_ptr<Base>'
I have a simple example of using virtual functions. Here is my structure:
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    
    Derived(int x, int y): Base(x, y) {}
    
    int func(int n) {
        return n;    // Some dummy function
    }
    
};

class Base {
public:
    
    Base(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    
    virtual int func(int n) const;
    
    ~virtual Base() = default;
    
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

In my main cpp file, I am initializing a unique_ptr like this:
std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr = std::make_unique<Derived>(10, 10);

This gives me the error:
No viable conversion from 'unique_ptr<Derived>' to 'unique_ptr<Base>'

Now this example is part of a bigger codebase which have no other errors. When I tried the same thing in a standalone file, it wasn't giving any errors. What's wrong?

Your first snippet can't compile since Base isn't defined before you try to inherit from it.  [Edit] your question with a real [mcve].

I can't reproduce this (after the obvious compilation errors are fixed) : https://godbolt.org/z/YPM7f9r1j

This code won't compile for at least a couple of reasons, including ~virtual Base() is not valid syntax for a destructor, and class Base must be declared before class Derived in order for class Derived to inherit from it.  Could you correct the code and attempt again?

you are likely missing a #include somewhere and one of the types is incomplete because it was forward declared elsewhere, or you are missing public inheritance in your actual code so it is private inheritance in your actual code.

Also, Derived::func is not overriding Base::func due to the missing const on the end of the declaration. The compiler would flag that mistake as a fatal error had you used override on Derived::func, otherwise it is reported as just a warning at best.
